# Change GridView columns header

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, sqldatasource

I'm using the next SQLDataSource Select cmnd :

```
        SelectCommand="SELECT [itemTitle] 
     FROM orders
     INNER JOIN items
     on orders.itemId = items.itemId
     WHERE costumerId = @costumerId ">
```

The gridview code:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
    DataSourceID="UserProfileOrder" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>


    </Columns>
```

As you see, the  is empty, but it's get the details from the SQLDataSource... so the outpot is:

### itemTitle

bla bla bla

There is way to change the header title? for now, it's display the name of the column from the SELECT command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your select query write like

```
select [itemTitle] as Header1
 FROM orders
```